# Svelte tick() not forcing updates to variables

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have run into what seems like a common problem in svelte but haven't found a good solution. I have a function that is called when a button is pressed in a component, the basic situation is shown below.

```
<script>
import tick from 'svelte'

let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let z = 0;
async function buttonHandler() {
     --- multiple computationally intensive loops 
        that update the vars x,y,z at different points ---
    e.g.
    for (a in arr) {

        x ++;
        await tick();
    }
}
</script>

<main>
    <button on:click={buttonHandler}>Click Me</button>
    <p>{x}</p>
    <p>{y}</p>
    <p>{z}</p>
</main>
```

I basically wanted the x, y, z values to update on screen as the function incremented them, to have live updates of the progress. Originally they were not updating until the function completed, and I read that it was because svelte batch updates changes to  reactive variables. I then read that the 'tick()' function was designed for this situation, to 'flush' the updates and have the DOM rerender the updated values. However this still isn't working, the only way I can get it work is by replacing tick() with a generic sleep() function:

```
function sleep(millisec = 0) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(_ => resolve(), millisec);
        });
    };
```

This doesn't seem like its a good solution, and I feel like I must be missing something. Have any others had situations where tick isn't working as expected?

Comment: *"However this still isn't working"* What exactly happens?

Comment: @FelixKling With 'tick()' the values on the webpage remain at 0 until the function terminates, and only then are they updated on the webpage to their final totals. The behavior I need is for the individual increments to be displayed on the webpage as the function executes e.g. 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 vs. 1 -> 4 . This is possible using the 'sleep()' workaround.

Comment: Can you provide a more accurate example of your actual code?

Comment: Just a heads up, `tick` is not the default export from svelte. You need to use `import { tick } from 'svelte'` instead to import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `afterUpdate` function to check that you flush as expected

```js
import { tick, afterUpdate } from 'svelte';

afterUpdate(() => {
//This should log multiple times, one for every expected value change after tick()
 console.log(x, y ,z);
})
```

I tried your code in REPL, added basic loops that update every 100x loop, and it still looks instant, but the logs show it did update correctly. So the `flush` does not trigger a new render like in React (blocks the thread), instead, it has its own batched schedule. To work around this and keep things reactive, and not looking clunky they suggest using CSS animations to get the desired smooth effect. CSS animations don't block the main thread.

> "When you update component state in Svelte, it doesn't update the DOM
> immediately. Instead, it waits until the next microtask to see if
> there are any other changes that need to be applied, including in
> other components. Doing so avoids unnecessary work and allows the
> browser to batch things more effectively."

from: (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick)[https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick]

So this is why it looks instant in your case.

You can see here how they solved this with a tween animation:

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tweened

So they slow things down with animations which does NOT slow down or block the main thread like `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or a dom render does.

UPDATED
better example here: https://svelte.dev/repl/c2856360456c40e98ace08438e5bf82f?version=3.38.2

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate the exact code in REPL as it uses some statements which REPL considers infinite loops (but the code works on my machine). Am I missing something with your linked REPL, to me it looks like both buttons do the same thing so not sure what I'm missing. Tick import isn't problem, was just there for demo purposes.

Comment: updated the answer, too little space here

Comment: I understand the problem is that tick() is failing to 'force' to force a microtask release for some reason. Using a tweened value is not a solution as the value will still not be changed until the function has finished executing, but yes there will be smooth effect interpolating the values at the end, but there will be no feedback on the webpage while the function is executing (which is what I need).

Comment: updated answer: here's a better example I created of how I would try solving your issue:

https://svelte.dev/repl/c2856360456c40e98ace08438e5bf82f?version=3.38.2

Comment: I can't test the updated example directly as I'm further ahead in development now but that updated demo shows that the auxiliary function should solve the problem.